# Issue Setting Pivot Table Filter Using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Community,

I am trying to "default" some filtering so that users save time / reduce errors for some recurring reports, but stuck on setting the Pivot Field "RT...1004 : "Unable to get the PivotFields property of the PivotTable Class".

The field does exist, with that name (tried other ones too). The PT itself refers to a data table in excel.

Looking at examples around the web I really don't see an error in below code, but obviously there is. The code does work if I comment out the "Set pf01" and pf01.CurrentPage, the filters are then all cleared so the references to pivottable are correct..

```
Sub TestSetpvt()

Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim pvt As PivotTable
Dim pf01 As PivotField

Set wks = ActiveSheet
Set pvt = wks.PivotTables("RPT_OTH")
Set pf01 = pvt.PivotFields("Q_INCL")

pvt.ClearAllFilters

pf01.CurrentPage = "Y"
```

Comment: this explanation is not very clear. Can you add more information please.

Comment: Not sure what you really want, but have you considered conditional formatting? cells that only accept numbers within a range or integer or accept text  or particular words... Data validation is also a possibility...

Comment: The issue is that the command 'Set pf01 = pvt.PivotFields("Q_INCL") ' throws the error RT...1004 : "Unable to get the PivotFields property of the PivotTable Class". As if the field doesn't exist ..

Comment: The code you posted works without issue for me. I tried that with a dummy data table. Can you send a screenshot of your pivot table, maybe just the upper left corner of it?

Comment: Also, i believe that your field "Q_INCL" has to be a filter field. If it is a row field i think that you might not be able to achieve the filtering in this way.

Comment: Thanks for the help, however it is a filter field. I can gen by the error of setting the variable if a set the field like this 'Set pf01 = pvt.PivotFields("[TBL_TCB].[Q_INCL].[Q_INCL]")', but it fails then when using pf01.currentpage = "Y")

Answer (score 0):

I tested a couple of things and was able to reproduce your issue. 
You need to have your field "Q_INCL" as a filter field for your filtering to work with the code you provided.

if it is a row field, you will get the error you posted.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This works.., looks like this part of excel / excel vba is more complex then I'd like it to be :-/

```
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim pvt As PivotTable
Dim pf01 As PivotField

Set wks = ActiveSheet
Set pvt = wks.PivotTables("RPT_OTH")
Set pf01 = pvt.PivotFields("[TBL_TCB].[Q_INCL].[Q_INCL]")

pf01.VisibleItemsList = Array("[TBL_TCB].[Q_INCL].&[Y]")
```